# Pass different types of parameter to enum in java

Tags: java, android

I'm new in Java and trying to create enum which can accept different parameters.
e.g.

```
public enum EnumTest {
  Version {
    @Override
    public String getValue(int var) {
        return "";
    }
  },
  Time {
    @Override
    public String getValue(Date date) {
        return "";
    }
 };

public abstract String getValue();
}
```

Now in above example I'm using `getValue()` method with two different types. which gives me an error.

Could someone please let me know how can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please give bit more details on what you are trying to do and what error are you getting?

Comment: @Jinnah I'm trying to pass runtime values to enum and depending upon that it actually create string and return to its calling place.
It says me to create multiple abstract methods with same name but different argument types and I want to create single method fo all enum types.

Comment: You...basically can't do this.  Not anything like that.